# c: last loop in if elseif else is not working

Tags: c, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to solve an error on the loop in code below but I can't figure out why it won't go again in first "if", after in last "else" ("Introduceti d sau n! "), I write 'n'. The 'd' is working fine and going back to "else if". In the last revised code, I've updated with the working code. At least, it works after I press 'n' in last "else" sentence and is taking me back to first menu.

#### Original code

```
switch(alegere_opt1)
{
    case 1:
        while(decizie != 'n')
        {          
            alegereStudent(&stud);
            printf("Doriti sa introduceti un nou student? (d/n):");
            scanf(" %c",&decizie);
            if (decizie == 'n')
                {
                meniuPrincipal();
                alegereStudent(&stud);
                printf("Doriti sa introduceti un nou student? (d/n):");
                scanf(" %c",&decizie);
                }
            else if (decizie == 'd')
                {
                alegereStudent(&stud);
                printf("Doriti sa introduceti un nou student? (d/n):");
                scanf(" %c",&decizie);
                }
            else
                {
                printf("Introduceti d sau n! ");
                scanf(" %c",&decizie);
                }
        }
        break;
```

#### Revised code:

```
switch(alegere_opt1)
{
case 1:
{           
            alegereStudent(&stud);
            printf("Doriti sa introduceti un nou student? (d/n): ");
            scanf(" %c",&decizie);
                 if (decizie == 'n')
                    {
                    meniuPrincipal();
                    alegereStudent(&stud);
                    }

                   else if (decizie == 'd')
                    {
                    alegereStudent(&stud);
                    }
                    else
                     {
                    printf("Introduceti d sau n! ");
                    scanf(" %c",&decizie);
                     }
}
break;
```

#### Revised code correct:

```
    switch(alegere_opt1)
{
     case 1: while (decizie != 'z')
     {          
                {          
            alegereStudent(&stud);
            printf("Doriti sa introduceti un nou student? (d/n):");
            scanf(" %c",&decizie);
            if (decizie == 'd')
                {
                alegereStudent(&stud);
                printf("Doriti sa introduceti un nou student? (d/n):");
                scanf(" %c",&decizie);
                }
            else if (decizie == 'n')
                {
                meniuPrincipal();
                }
            else
                {
                printf("Introduceti d sau n! ");
                scanf(" %c",&decizie);
                    if (decizie == 'n')
                    {
                    meniuPrincipal();
                    }
                }

                }
     }
        break;
```

Comment: the condition of your `while-loop` is `decizie != 'n'`, so it will break out of the loop.

Comment: even if I delete the while, it won't work

Comment: Make a function which you call from the switch case instead.

Comment: Well, if you enter 'n' in the last else (immediately after "Introduceti d sau n! "), that will be the value of 'decizie', which is then immediately checked by the while loop condition `!= 'n'`. If you remove the `scanf(" %c",&decizie);` in the else clause, I think you'll get the result you're looking for.

Comment: Note that the `if`, `else if` and `else` blocks all end with the same statement, `scanf(" %c", &decizie);`.  You could move that call outside the conditional chain so you have only one copy of it.  That would then leave you with two of those calls in each iteration, one after the call to `alegereStudent()`, one at the end.  That might be OK; it's hard to tell what the function does.  OTOH, there seems to be too much repetition (three lots of the same `printf()` call?) and so on.  You need to rethink where you do inputs, I think.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler .  I went back and looked at the code and I missed the blank before the %c ... so, my solution was incorrect and I withdrew it.  You were right :)

Comment: How are you entering your input ?  Single character followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: @Hogstrom yes, 'n' or 'd' than Enter key.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've remade the code as you can see above in edit, but still won't work.

Comment: Please don't invalidate previous answers by editing the code.  Add the revision, as I've done for you this time.  If Google's understanding of Romanian is valid, your `elegereStudent()` function 'selects' or 'chooses' a student.  Your revised code doesn't have a loop in it.  That makes `decizie` a little odd.  Should you have a loop `while (decizie != 'n' && decizie != 'd')` with `decizie = 'z'; (or any other character than `n` or `d`) before the loop?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've made it work. I added the revised code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't figure out why it won't go again in first "if", after in last
>   "else" ("Introduceti d sau n! "), I write 'n'. The 'd' is working fine
>   and going back to "else if".

Because of your `while` loop condition(`while(decizie != 'n')`). Loop will execute as long as you give anything but `n` as input. It won't go in the first `if` as you're giving `n` as the input.

Comment: Per the code, this is not true. They can enter 'n' immediately after `"Doriti sa introduceti un nou student? (d/n):"`, which will go into the first if clause, where they are prompted again.

Comment: @schil227 *which will go into the first if clause,* - before that the condition will be checked and the loop will be terminated.

Comment: @schil227 *but I can't figure out why it won't go again in first "if", after in last "else" ("Introduceti d sau n! "), I write 'n'* - how is it possible to execute the body of `while ` when the user gives `n` as input???

Comment: @suvojit_007 even if I remove the while condition, it won't work

Comment: @Why will it work if you remove the `while`? Try to understand the flow of your program. It will only work if you give anything but `n` as your input.